# updating a max value of a range

Tags: excel, max, formulas

I have a P79=SUM(K14:N73) and need a cell to track the maximum total of the those cells. The cells values do change weekly. If last weeks totals were more then this weeks total it will only keep the maximum value.

When using P79=SUM(K14:N73)  p80=(cell I put this formula into)-->   =IF(P79>P80,P79,P80)
it comes back with a **circular reference warning** and the value is 0.

Am I not entering it right? I need it to hold the Maximum Weekly Value, hopefully Without using visual basic, I do not know how to use that or set it up to work. But if I must... I must!

Comment: Your formula in p80 is referring to itself, which about as circular as you can get.  You'll need some cell to hold Last Week's Maximum, a *different* one to do the comparison & some way of updating the LWM cell each week.

Comment: 2 upvotes in the first few minutes for an unclear formula question!

Comment: Can you post an example of the numbers you mean to get, and(or state the question more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either use a macro for this task or multiple cells.  Here is a typical macro you would run after entering new data in the table:

```
Sub SaveMax()
    ' =IF(P79>P80,P79,P80)
    If [P79] > [P80] Then
        [P80] = [P79]
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting the formula in cell p80, and the formula itself references P80 (which it does) then I can see how you would get that warning.

```
P80 = IF(P79>P80,P79,P80)
```

Excel doesn't like circular references by default, but you can enable what is called "iterave calculation"

In Excel, go to *File -> Options->Formulas*

Check the box labeled "Enable iterative calculation" and set the maximum iterations to 1

This allows excel to run the formula (iterate) once, instead of "looping" forever.

Check out this link for some more details on how I found this

https://www.udemy.com/blog/circular-reference-excel/